# Movie about robots from mid to early 2000's

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

There is a movie that I watched when I was very young (I'm talking around mid-early 2000's), though I can not remember it. But here is what I remember from it:

- There was a young man that was in this Science complex.
- In this science complex, there was a large number of robots that had white smooth plating (their heads and bodies were very well shaped to look like a human).
- While in this science complex, there was one robot in particular the man befriended, there was LOTS of hostile robots.
- There was a long range camera shot of the man running along a high up path  with a rail and a colossal drop on the other side of the rail.
- The place he was in was dark, bluish and whitish all in one (to look like a science fiction movie) the drop had a the same sort of colour. The surrounding space was a dull blue grey colour.
- The friendly robot was a fast runner and the man was trying to get away from it but the robot caugth up to him, the man said (I think):

  > 'What do you want from me'?

I feel like this is when the man was about to fall over a drop and when the robot was trying to either help him up or do something else I can't remember.

- When the robot moves, it made this machine like screaming sound. The robot did talk, though I can't remember what it said.
- The robot was after that protecting the man from other robots trying to kill the man in this massive (colossal) science complex.
- I remember there being some sort of blue sheet like wall that looked like a water fall, but made of some material that robots could pass through easily, and the robot used it to get to the man while chasing him (I think the man ws trying to destroy or lose the robot in some way I can't remember).
- I can't remember the ending at all but I know that the robot ends up getting destroyed (head first) by other robots in an attempt to save the man. The sparks thrown by the robot while being destroyed were a deep blue colour and the robots head snapped to the side.
- When the robot fell to the ground destroyed, it fell in a fluid and smooth like movement, sort of like someone being shot and fall to the ground.
- The movie I believe was filmed in the USA in between the 80's and year 2000. Somewhere in that time frame.

[image: The robot looked something like this, only the eyes were blue and round, smaller with a black ring of hollow going around the eye.]

<sub>The robot looked something like this, only the eyes were blue and round, smaller with a black ring of hollow going around the eye.</sub>

Comment: I don't know, it could be, but if memory dosn't fail me then I am sure the man was caucasian.

Comment: There was no particular order in detail, I was just throwing what I knew out there and hope that someone knew what I was on about.

Comment: I can't watch it, being in school, it is blocked. That is what you get if you go to school in Australia.

Comment: He means I, Robot. Will smith is not white.

Comment: Oh, I would have done an I, Robot answer, too, but I figured it got debunked in the comments with "He was white, I think" so I decided not to bother :P Even went on IMDB to do my usual Google-Fu, and the only plausible answer was I, Robot. Ah well, haha @Gnemlock

Comment: Surely you mean "early-mid"! Seeing them in the reverse order is just *weird*.

Comment: Why is this a supposed duplicate of another question. I checked the other supposed question out and it is a completely different set out and description,  would not have been able to identify the movie from somehting like that. It is asking for the same movie but a completely different way around it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It vaguely sounds like you *might* be thinking of [I, Robot](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0343818/), which was released in 2004, starring Will Smith. Your description is a bit vague, as most of it sounds generic to the "Sci Fi with Robots"; you also report that you *remember* the protagonist being Caucassian; but imply that you are *not 100% sure*. As such, here is a trailer, and an analysis of your recollections.

---

> **[I, Robot (2004)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0343818/)** 
> In 2035, a technophobic cop investigates a crime that may have been perpetrated by a robot, which leads to a larger threat to humanity.

---

> "There was a young man that was in this Science complex. In this science complex, there was a large number of robots that had white smooth plating (their heads and bodies were very well shaped to look like a human)."

Will Smith's character makes several trips to the facility where the robots are actually made, in I, Robot. The robots are designed to look human, and look very much like the example image you posted.

[image]

> "While in this science complex, there was one robot in particular the man befriended, there was LOTS of hostile robots."

This strongly reminds me of a scene that occurs towards the end of the movie.

> The "main character" robot, Sonny, returns to the factory with Will Smith. At this point, the robots have effectively "gone rogue", and all start attacking them. Sonny protects Will, before going off by himself. By this point, Will's character has befriended Sonny, and learnt to trust him.

This would imply that you remember this scene in reverse-order, but you have commented that that *may* be the case.

> "The place he was in was dark, bluish and whitish all in one (to look like a science fiction movie) the drop had a the same sort of colour. The surrounding space was a dull blue grey colour."

The general factory, itself, features a lot of blue and white colours. In fact, a general blueish hue can be found, in other scenes. This sounds pretty generic, however, to the "Sci-Fi with Robots" genre.

[image]
[image]

> "There was a long range camera shot of the man running along a high up path with a rail and a colossal drop on the other side of the rail. **..** The friendly robot was a fast runner and the man was trying to get away from it but the robot caugth<sup>[sic]</sup> up to him, the man said (I think): 'What do you want from me'?

I can not recall any specific scenes exactly as you describe; however, there are several scenes that enforce the physical capabilities of the robots, both in running speed and ability to fall from height. There is one particular scene where a robot falls from a height, and leaves impact scars on the ground, below. What *does* throw me off is the recollection of the robot chasing the main character; from as best as I can remember, it would be the other way around.

> The main robot, Sonny, is accused of murdering his creator and the inventor of said robots; the entire plot revolves around the significant proof, and the fact that robots do not kill humans. There is a scene where Will's character must chase Sonny, who flees during Will's initial encounter.

Naturally, this is again very generic. It is not uncommon for Sci-Fi robots to be shown as having greater speed and endurance than a regular human being.

> "I feel like this is when the man was about to fall over a drop and when the robot was trying to either help him up or do something else I can't remember."

This reminds me of a scene where Will's character is *drowning*, and a robot tries to pull him out of the car.

> This might also account for your vague memory of the words "What do you want from me"; Will's character is stuck in a car that has gone into the lake, alongside a child. The robots logic tells it that Will's character has a greater chance of survival, due to being a fully grown adult, and saves Will's character, much to his protests. As a result, the child dies. This serves as the root cause of Will's robo-phobia.

This would mainly correlate to remembering a robot "pulling the main character up".

> "When the robot moves, it made this machine like screaming sound. The robot did talk, though I can't remember what it said."

I can not recall any particular sound the robots make, though they did talk. The main robot, Sonny, naturally talks a lot more; but all robots had the ability to talk, and interacted as such.

> "I remember there being some sort of blue sheet like wall that looked like a water fall, but made of some material that robots could pass through easily, and the robot used it to get to the man while chasing him (I think the man ws trying to destroy or lose the robot in some way I can't remember)."

This reminds me of one of the final scenes.

> Sonny attempts to destroy the main computer responsible for the robots "going rogue", and finds that the main computer is shielded by an energy field. Sonny comments on how his creator made him out of a special alloy, and he never knew why, until he got to the main computer; this special alloy allows him to pass through the force field, in order to inject nanites that would kill the main computer.

---

I feel I may have missed the mark, as so much seems generic enough to easily apply; and yet, so much seems to bare stark similarity. I may have missed or mis-remembered minor details from I, Robot; but the main aspects are accurate.

Comment: You just about nailed it, that was the movie, thanks.

Comment: damn good answer :)

Comment: Minor correction to an otherwise amazing answer : "his special alloy allows him to pass through the force field, and remove the main computers power cores" The force field was used as a container for **nanites** (used to kill positronic robot brains, which were shown and discussed when Sonny would be executed early in the movie). These nanites would later be used to disable the main villain by injecting them into its core.

Comment: @Flater, I thought I'd got the power core thing wrong. Cheers

Comment: Small typo - the IMDB link text says 2014, but it's a 2004 movie (as you correctly mention elsewhere in the answer)

Comment: Also the answer to [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/71038/44222).